# Forty and five, not five and forty

Tags: number, vayera

In [Bereishis 18:28](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.18.28?lang=bi&aliyot=0), when Hashem says that He will not destroy Sedom if there are 45 righteous people there, the number is spelled out "forty and five." However, most times a number between twenty and one hundred is mentioned the ones digit is said first and then the tens, such as in [Bereishis 5:15](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.5.15?lang=bi&aliyot=0). Why the exception?

I would prefer an answer according to peshat, but an answer according to derash is better than no answer.